# I want to use the IP address of the Site visitors instead of a proxy

Tags: javascript, jquery, http, proxy, instagram-api

I want to use the ip address of the users who log in to the site. They will send followers to each other with their own ip addresses. I have a system for sending followers but it works with a proxy. How can I solve without a proxy using users' ip address?

eg 500 instant visitors = 500 ip addresses. Approximately 200 entries can be made to Instagram with 1 ip address

Comment: Which IP address? the one the user's device has in it's local network, or the one the server sees?

Comment: What do IP addresses and Proxies have to do with JS? May you share a [mcve] of your issue?

Comment: @JonasWilms I want to send followers to each other by using the ip addresses of instant users on my site. For example, there are 500 users, which means that I can use 500 ip addresses.Approximately 200 entries can be made via Instagram with 1 ip address.

Comment: @evolutionxbox Xml, http, request. With the terms I mentioned I thought could be done with JavaScript

Comment: Do you want to spoof the IP address?

Comment: @x43 Yes. Everyone on the site will use each other's ip address

Comment: Thats going to be fairly difficult as a lot of hosts and ISPs have systems in place to check that IP spoofing is not occurring.